# In Tomcat 6.0 The requested resource (/Purchase detail) is not availaible- 404 error found

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Jsp Code

```
<h1>Good one</h1>
<form action = "/PurchaseDetails" method = "post">
        <table id="tab1" align="center" border="0">
        <tr><th>Purchased Details</th></tr>
        <tr><td style="padding-left:50px;"></td><td>Date</td><td   style="padding-left:50px;"></td><td><input type="text" name="uname" id="date" class="calendar"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="padding-left:50px;"></td><td>Total Quantity</td><td style="padding-left:50px;"></td><td><input type="text" name="totalquantity" id="totalquantity"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="padding-left:50px;"></td><td>Total Weight</td><td style="padding-left:50px;"></td><td><input type="text" name="totalweight" id="totalweight"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="btn1" id="btn1" value="Update"/></td><td><input type = "reset" value = "Cancel"/></td></tr>

</table>
```

i given like this in the Jsp page.
When i run this one index page is running. After if i gave the values in and click the submit button means

HTTP Status 404 - /PurchaseDetails

type Status report

message /PurchaseDetails

description The requested resource (/PurchaseDetails) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.14

It will through this error. What can i do? If any one knows means tell me how can i do further
    My Web.xml code is here:
      
      
      PurchaseDetails
      PurchaseDetails
      com.focus.controller.PurchaseDetails
      
      
      PurchaseDetails
      /PurchaseDetails

Comment: You have a servlet (with post) listening in /PurchaseDetails? please add it and the relevant part of the web.xml

Comment: Do you have a servlet configured for the path "/PurchaseDetails"? The error message means that the POST of the form has arrived ad the tomcat but the tomcat now doesn't know who is responsible for handling this request since it cannot find a suitable configuration

Comment: Can you please post `web.xml` file ?

Comment: <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>PurchaseDetails</display-name>
    <servlet-name>PurchaseDetails</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.focus.controller.PurchaseDetails</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PurchaseDetails</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PurchaseDetails</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>